# How to contest a migrated question?

Tags: discussion, migration

Is there a way to contest, if I don't agree with the migration of my question?

More specifically, I recently posted a question about reading a PDF file with Poppler to retrieve given information. However, as this question deals with a PDF file generated by LaTeX, [it was migrated to TeX group](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97211/is-it-possible-to-distinguish-between-note-and-normal-slide-in-pdf-generated-usi). I don't agree with that move, since my question really is about programming. What should I do with that?

Comment: You can yell at a wall, or yell at a mod. You will fare better yelling at the wall, though.

Answer (score 3):

You can contest a migration by posting on Meta, which you've already done.

You can also flag your migrated question. That's generally preferred - less noise for everyone. Click the *flag* link just below the tags in your question, select "other", and describe why you think your question shouldn't have been migrated.